# can anyone provide a sample for call zlib in objectivc-c to extract a compressed folder?

Tags: objective-c, zlib

I'm programming a iPhone app. Now I want to extract a gziped file (contain folder hierarchy) with objective-c. Currently I know "zlib" can do it, but I don't know how to use it in objective-c.

I don't want the wrapper package "minizip" be imported, just want to use "zlib" directly.

Can anybody help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Objective-C is a [superset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963832/is-objective-c-2-0-a-proper-superset-of-c) of C, you'd [use zlib](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html) the same as in any C program. If you want an Objective-C interface, try the [NSDataExtension category](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDataCategory) over at CocoaDev.