# Interview - Intergrating c++ libraries with iOS app

Tags: ios, c, xcode, integration

I was asked this about a month back. It is not exactly my line of work, yet I'm curious. They basically had some music libraries in C and wanted to make them available for ios code.

If I have some .c or .cpp files. How can I use them in an ios project. Again this can be confusing as I'm not giving you any context. But any useful links or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add them to the project, you don't have to do anything special. XCode (and clang) will know what language they are from the extension and compile them appropriately.

You *might* need to tell xcode to link to `libstdc++`, but that would be it.

Comment: No need to change `.cpp` to `.mm` anymore?

Comment: @MikeD nope, xcode handles cpp just fine (and even has a template for it). Though if you want to use aspects of both, you need to name it .mm.

Comment: So, only if there is a reference to a foundation object requires the `.mm` extension.

Comment: Technically, a reference to any objective c object, which I believe doesn't necessarily need to be foundation.

Answer (score 2):

iOS is based on Objective-C which is a superset of C.  For all intents and purposes, things should "just work" when compiling C under objective-C.  All your structs, function pointers, and everything else you learned in C are still valid and should compile under objective-C.

In-fact, some of the iOS framework pieces (CF, etc) are written in C.

[Is objective C 2.0 a proper superset of C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963832/is-objective-c-2-0-a-proper-superset-of-c)

C++, however, is a different matter :)