# Does swift support C natively?

Tags: ios, swift

Objective C can compile C natively. Objective C was built over C. Can swift do the same? If not what are the differences.

Comment: Well, the Swift compiler doesn't compile C, but you can mix C and Swift in an Xcode project and they can call each other.

Comment: Objc is a superset of C. Swift was made to interoperate with Objc APIs including C APIs but you cannot combine C code and Swift code in one file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike Objective-C, [which is a proper superset of C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2963832/335858), Swift has been built as an entirely new language. Swift cannot compile C code because the syntax is not compatible.

Swift can interoperate wit C code (see [*Interacting with C APIs*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html) article for more information). However, C code behind the APIs needs to be compiled separately, using a C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Swift uses swift compiler to parse and then LLVM to optimise and generate code. Hence swift compiler cannot parse C syntax.

As ObjectiveC uses clang compiler(which compiles C, C++, ObjectiveC languages) which generate syntax tree and LLVM for optimisation and code generation. Hence we can use C along with Objective C. So the Clang can parse the C/C++/objective C code, generate syntax tree, do semantic analysis and LLVM does back end compilation.